# How to make awk produce columns

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have a file with two columns. Each line in this file has a different size of words

```
awk '$5=$9' FS="#" OFS="\t" file1**


Tomato#Vegetable
Orange#Fruit
Cucumber#Vegetable
Sweat Potato#Fruit
```

This line of code makes it like this:

```
Tomato   Vegetable
Orange   Fruit
Cucumber   Vegetable
Sweat Potato    Fruit
```

I am trying to make this file be displayed like this:

```
Tomato          Vegetable
Orange          Fruit
Cucumber        Vegetable
Sweat Potato    Fruit
```

What am I doing wrong that does not give me this result?

Comment: `$5=$9` doesn't make sense as an action given your 2-field input, nor does it make sense as a condition given you don't need to decide whether to print or not base on its result.

Comment: I just started to learn and practice this linux command. I am trying my best to get the concept out of practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Unix / Linux you can use `column` to produce column output:

```
$ column -t -s '#' your_file
Tomato        Vegetable
Orange        Fruit
Cucumber      Vegetable
Sweat Potato  Fruit
```

To do it in `awk` you can read the file twice to get the max field length for each column. Once you do that, you can fix the field width with `sprintf` with the [field width](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html) + pad value:

```
awk -F'#' -v pad=4 '
        FNR==NR {                    # FNR==NR means first file
            for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)      # find the max width of each field
                if(max[i]<length($i)) max[i]=length($i)
            next                     # next record of first file
            } 
            {                        # Second file
                s=""                 # reset the buffer string
                for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)  # build the buffer field by field
                    s=s sprintf("%-*s%*s", max[i], $i, pad, "")
                print s              # print the buffer
            } '    your_file your_file
```

Prints:

```
Tomato        Vegetable  
Orange        Fruit      
Cucumber      Vegetable  
Sweat Potato  Fruit
```

Comment: @EdMorton: As always -- thanks for your valuable help and expertise.

Answer (score 2):

Another awk, that reads the file once, hashes the records to memory (expected that you have enough memory available) and format and outputs in the end:

```
$ awk -F\# '{                              # define record separator
    a[NR]=$1                               # store 1st field
    b[NR]=$2                               # store 2nd field
    m=((n=length($1))>m?n:m)               # figure out the max length of 1st field
}
END {                                      # in the end
    for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)                     # iterate stored fields
        printf "%-" m+4 "s%s\n",a[i],b[i]  # output
}' file
```

Output:

```
Tomato          Vegetable
Orange          Fruit
Cucumber        Vegetable
Sweat Potato    Fruit
```